# Consul not showing services registered in different node

Tags: consul, service-discovery, spring-cloud-consul

I have a cluster of 3 nodes of consul servers. I have registered one service(FooService) with one of the server(Server1). When i check the registered services using http (/v1/agent/services) from the server(Server1) it is showing correctly. But when i try the same with any of other server(ie, Server1 /Server2) its not listing this registered service. This issue is not happening for KV Store. Can someone suggest a fix for this?

> consul version : 1.2.1

I have pasted my configuration below

```
{
"bootstrap_expect": 3,
"client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
"datacenter": "DC1",
"data_dir": "/var/consul",
"domain": "consul",
"enable_script_checks": true,
"dns_config": {
    "enable_truncate": true,
    "only_passing": true
},
"enable_syslog": true,
"encrypt": "3scwcXQpgNVo1CZuqlSouA==",
"leave_on_terminate": true,
"log_level": "INFO",
"rejoin_after_leave": true,
"server": true,
"start_join": [
    "10.0.0.242",
    "10.0.0.243",
    "10.0.0.244"
],
"ui": true
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consul Agent Service Registrations on other nodes are not fetchable from Rest API but is showing on UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890740/consul-agent-service-registrations-on-other-nodes-are-not-fetchable-from-rest-ap)

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is , spring boot app should always connect to local consul client. Then this issue will not occur.