# Consul Agent Service Registrations on other nodes are not fetchable from Rest API but is showing on UI

Tags: consul, service-discovery

We have a consul cluster of 3 servers and registering agent services on any of them via Rest Api.

In UI, registrations of a server are visible on other servers as well. For e.g. registration on server A is visible on server B's UI (accessible by http://serverb:8500/).

However when hitting server B via Rest Api, it only shows its own registrations and do not show server A registration.

Server are started as
**Server A**
consul -server -ui bootstrap-expect=1 -node=ServerA -data-dir=D:\data -bind=11.223.15.78 -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=11.223.15.79 -retry-join=11.223.15.80

**Server B**

consul -server -ui bootstrap-expect=1 -node=ServerB -data-dir=D:\data -bind=11.223.15.79 -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=11.223.15.78 -retry-join=11.223.15.80

**Server C**

consul -server -ui bootstrap-expect=1 -node=ServerC -data-dir=D:\data -bind=11.223.15.80 -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=11.223.15.78 -retry-join=11.223.15.79

Is this an issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visibility of services will depend on which API endpoint you're using, and where you're registering your services. Consul intends for services to be registered against a Consul client agent which is running on the same host as the deployed service. The services registered with each agent in the data center are aggregated to form the service catalog (https://www.consul.io/docs/architecture/anti-entropy#catalog).

The [`/catalog/services`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/catalog#list-services) endpoint returns an aggregated list of services registered with each agent across the data center. The [`/agent/services`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#list-services) endpoint will only return services registered against the specific local agent with which you are communicating.

If you want clients to be able to register services across any server, you'll want to register them using the [`/catalog/register`](https://www.consul.io/api/catalog#register-entity) endpoint. You can optionally use a tool like [Consul External Services Monitor](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-esm) to provide health checking for services, independently from the Consul servers. See https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/consul-and-external-services for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I got to know this today from here https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/5657

Answer (score 0):

If a service has been registered via the agent api only on one consul node of a cluster, you can still query the service by its service name by means of the catalog api from all server nodes:

```
/v1/catalog/:servicename
```

See https://www.consul.io/api-docs/catalog#list-nodes-for-service

Note that you need to deregister a service on the same consul node *via the agent api* where you have registered it via the agent api in the first place. If you just deregister it from the catalog, it will be back after a few minutes (that is at least my experience)

The Consul documentation [recommends to use the agent api for registration](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/catalog#register-entity), so I would still stick to registering via the agent api, although it makes deregistering a bit tricky.

Comment: As a sidenote: the Camel ServiceCall mechanism uses the services from the catalog, so it works even if a service has only been registered with one server node using the agent api.